Is it possible to use my own admin panel template created in html, bootstrap for django admin panel
I am new in django and in admin customization i want to know is it possible to use own admin panel created in html, bootstrap instead of django built in admin , or is there any other django admin templates which i can use as built in admin not looks good.
i tried admin customization by overlapping the files but I think it is not the right thing is there any other solution , or i have to change the admin urls to my own admin template and have to do all the CRUD things by my own , as in django they are build in for models.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

check out this, i think it's basically the same question being posed here.
How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?
